# Strange behaviour of Java split function in Map Reduce hadoop

Tags: java, string, hadoop, split

I am trying to split a string by using `split()` function. Now my code is like this:

```
String s = "from1x1";
String [] parts = s.split("x");
```

now when I output my result by using below code, it shows output "from1"

```
System.out.println(parts[0]);
```

But when I try to output my result using below code, it throws exception `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`.

```
System.out.println(parts[1]);
```

This is the weirdest thing as this error is not thrown when i made simple java program, also not in Map function of hadoop. But only Reduce function of hadoop this error occurs. Someone know what is the problem here?

Comment: There must be some code between the two System outs and the ' String ... split("x")`... Please provide a minimal example code that replicates this behavior. ...

Comment: that code you posted can not throw that exception...

Comment: There is no code between two outputs, and still its giving error

Comment: Impossible. Either there is something else going on, or your input doesn't look like you expect it to look like. But the above code *can not* lead to that error.

Comment: And just to be precise: given your input, there is no other answer to give. In other words: we need a **real** [mcve]. Show us that production code that throws the exception, not your obviously not-creating-a-problem abstraction of it!

Comment: [link](http://ideone.com/FYow1A)    see link 103 to 112. it is throwing error. To make sure i just outputted s and got from1x1. and when i outputted parts[0] i got from1, but when i outputted parts[1], i got error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1.

Comment: It means that at least 1 of your `values` does not contain `x`

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh your answer was most helpful. thank you bro